# Need access to Apple Time Machine Backup on hard drive that was booted on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, mac, backup

I have a hard drive that I used for backing up an old Macbook via Time Machine (OSX Lion).  I accidentally booted the external drive on my Ubuntu box which seems to have have changed the MBR.

Now when I try to access the drive via a Mac it will not recognize the drive.  The data all seems to be fine, I just can't boot into the drive now.

Curious if anyone has any ideas on a fix?

Comment: What exactly does “I accidentally booted the external drive on my Ubuntu box” mean? Did you connect it to a Linux PC? Did you do anything with it?

Comment: I suppose you are using the verb _booting (into)_ in a rather uncommon way. The standard meaning of "booting (from a disk)" is _"starting a computer and attempting to launch the operating system from the specified disk"_, which makes no sense in the situation you are describing. Could you please specify more precisely what you have been trying?

Comment: Hi - have several hard drives in a generic chassis and didn't realize my Mac backup drive was mounted in the chassis.  When I booted up Ubuntu I plugged the drive in via USB to my machine to pull some files then realized it was the wrong drive.

Ubuntu mounted the drive so that I could use it.  That's how I think it corrupted the MBR for my Mac to access.

After realizing I then plugged the drive into my Mac but it now cannot recognize the drive via DiskDoctor.